# How can i verify my txs with my own full node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, hardware-wallet

Hey i run a full bitcoin+lightning node on a rpi. Can anyone eli5 me how can i verify my own tx if send some coins from an exchange to a public address i control?

Lets say i plug in my hw, send some coins, then i wanna actually verify if i got those coins or at least they are (verify able) on the  mempool waiting to be mined.

I have always struggled with the how do i really “verify, don’t trust” quote.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Your lightning client needs to somehow learn about incoming transactions, and it uses the node it's pointed to for that. If that is a full node you trust (because you operate it yourself), you automatically get that trust carried over to your lightning client.

Comment: @PieterWuille yeh i have no issues when i receive/send thru my node. My issue was more related when i do external tx, for example when a friend sends me to an address generated from my hw and the latter isn’t specially used with the full node.

Comment: @Lebwoski If you're talking about another wallet, the answer is the same: make that wallet use your full node for validation (many wallet implementations let you select a trusted full node to connect to).

Comment: @PieterWuille unfortunetly not the ledger live :( ! But soon willl start using it either with bitcoin core or electrum personal server ! Thanks again for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `gettransaction (TXID)` command that returns information about a transaction belonging to your wallet. Then just check the confirmations field.

Sample Call: `bitcoin-cli -testnet gettransaction 5a7d24cd665108c66b2d56146f244932edae4e2376b561b3d396d5ae017b9589`

Sample Response:

```
{
    "amount" : 0.00000000,
    "fee" : 0.00000000,
    "confirmations" : 106670,
    "blockhash" : "000000008b630b3aae99b6fe215548168bed92167c47a2f7ad4df41e571bcb51",
    "blockindex" : 1,
    "blocktime" : 1396321351,
    "txid" : "5a7d24cd665108c66b2d56146f244932edae4e2376b561b3d396d5ae017b9589",
    "walletconflicts" : [
    ],
    "time" : 1396321351,
    "timereceived" : 1418924711,
    "bip125-replaceable" : "no",
    "details" : [
        {
            "account" : "",
            "address" : "mjSk1Ny9spzU2fouzYgLqGUD8U41iR35QN",
            "category" : "send",
            "amount" : -0.10000000,
            "vout" : 0,
            "fee" : 0.00000000
        },
        {
            "account" : "doc test",
            "address" : "mjSk1Ny9spzU2fouzYgLqGUD8U41iR35QN",
            "category" : "receive",
            "amount" : 0.10000000,
            "vout" : 0
        }
    ],
    "hex" : "0100000001cde58f2e37d000eabbb60d9cf0b79ddf67cede6dba58732539983fa341dd5e6c010000006a47304402201feaf12908260f666ab369bb8753cdc12f78d0c8bdfdef997da17acff502d321022049ba0b80945a7192e631c03bafd5c6dc3c7cb35ac5c1c0ffb9e22fec86dd311c01210321eeeb46fd878ce8e62d5e0f408a0eab41d7c3a7872dc836ce360439536e423dffffffff0180969800000000001976a9142b14950b8d31620c6cc923c5408a701b1ec0a02088ac00000000"
}
```

Reference: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#gettransaction

Comment: I don't understand what this achieves. If it's a transaction in your own (full node) wallet, it wouldn't be there if it isn't valid. If it's a transaction of an external wallet, `gettransaction` won't work on it.

Comment: I literally can't argue with you. I read the question quickly and answered something else. (btw: huge fan! thanks for all!)